# Fullscreen UIWebView to underlap UINavigationBar

Tags: ios, uiwebview, uinavigationcontroller, uinavigationbar

I have a UIViewController that contains a fullscreen UIWebView. This view controller will be contained inside a navigation controller. I actually *want* this view controller web view to underlap the navigation bar. Which is the proper way to achieve this?

If the view controller does not contain the web view I can see it underlapping the navigation bar:

[image]

```
UIViewController *newController = [[UIViewController alloc] init];
newController.view.backgroundColor = [UIColor greenColor];
newController.view.layer.borderWidth = 5;
newController.view.layer.borderColor = [UIColor redColor].CGColor;

UINavigationController *navController = [[UINavigationController alloc] initWithRootViewController:newController];
```

But it a UIWebView is added to the controller:

[image]

Using:

```
UIWebView *webView = [[UIWebView alloc] initWithFrame:newController.view.bounds];

[webView loadRequest:[NSURLRequest requestWithURL:[NSURL URLWithString:@"http://google.com"]]];
[newController.view addSubview:webView];
newController.edgesForExtendedLayout = UIRectEdgeTop;
```

I can still see the edges of the view controller underlapping the navigation bar, but the web view page starts below it, which I do not want.

Any ideas?

Thanks

Comment: Why don't you hide the navigation bar as opposed to trying to alter the UIWebViews frame.  Much more sane approach I think

Comment: I need the navigation bar to display a left bar button item. This will be a "settings" button which should always be in a consistent position, that is, I do not want to manually overlay a button view over the UIWebView; although tempting, as time goes by, I do not want to go down that road.